# iTextsharp to protect PDF file with long password

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm using the following code to protect a PDF file using iTextsharp library.

```
public Boolean ProtectPDF(String sourceFile, String newFile, String UserPassword, String OwnerPassword)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] USER = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(UserPassword);
            byte[] OWNER = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(OwnerPassword);
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(sourceFile);
            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create));
            stamper.SetEncryption(USER, OWNER, PdfWriter.AllowPrinting, PdfWriter.ENCRYPTION_AES_128);
            stamper.Close();
            reader.Close();

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

It works well for "short" password, such as **1234567890ABCDE=GHIJ12**.

If I try to apply with a "long" password such as **2017DgFLcnODOy8=7D-+0|Fk/2?g-=02d^xz-d3s@2|WiuXjQJoRBU=** , i found that only the **first 32 chars** was being recognized as the password, it seems that it doesn't matter for what chars I'm typing in, but the PDF file will still open.

Is there any limitation on PDF or ITextsharp library, or the problem is residing in the code?

Please advise, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a limitation inherent to the PDF specification, not a limitation of iText.

This is the relevant part of ISO 32000-1. It talks about a 32-byte string.

[image]

ISO 32000-1 is the specification for when you produce PDF 1.7 files. Since you are still mentioning iTextSharp (instead of iText for .NET), I am assuming that you are using an old iText version.

A couple of months ago, ISO 32000-2 was released, aka PDF 2.0. PDF 2.0 will be supported in iText 7.1. Longer passwords (up to 48 bytes) will be available in PDF 2.0.

If you use passwords that are longer than allowed in the spec, all the extra bytes will be ignored by iText.

Comment: Glad to see you again, so is that mean the PDF only recognized for the first 32 chars as the password?

Comment: I have updated my answer, adding the relevant part of ISO 32000-1. Once you decide you want to create PDF 2.0, you should upgrade your iText version to iText 7. We'll have PDF 2.0 support in version 7.1 (to be released soon). From that moment on, you'll be allowed to use 48-byte passwords.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I will decide whether to upgrade to iText 7.

Comment: Note that 7.1 isn't released yet. I should check with development when it's due.